# Does UnhookWindowsHookEx unload the library from the hooked application for a thread-specific hook?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

Assume I have a Windows hook procedure that I am installing on a specific thread using `SetWindowsHookEx`. When I subsequently call `UnhookWindowsHookEx`, is my DLL containing the hook procedure unloaded from the target application?

Most of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644960%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#installing_releasing) I've found on the subject would seem to imply that calling `SetWindowsHookEx` causes an implicit call to `LoadLibrary` in the target application. Also the docs are very careful to point out that calling `UnhookWindowsHookEx` on a *global* Windows hook does not implicitly free the library from all processes that may have loaded it, but are less than forthcoming on the subject of *thread-specific* hooks. I'm either not reading the documentation carefully enough, or my web search ability has failed me.

Comment: Quote: "The system eventually frees the DLL".  That will be a lot easier when only a single process has it loaded.  Exactly when it happens is undocumented, attach a debugger to see it happen.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between a thread specific hook and a global hook.  The thread ID parameter is just a filter which determines where the hook is applied - it doesn't change the hooking rules.

So either the thread ID parameter is for a different process and the same rules apply as for the global case - you can't safely inject a `FreeLibrary` call into another process, or the thread ID is part of your process and there is no reason to call `LoadLibary` since the DLL is already loaded before the call to `SetWindowsHookEx`.  (Or you passed NULL for the instance in which case there is no DLL)

I suspect the docs are use "global" to mean out of process and "thread" to be in process since that would be the normal case.  Hooking a single thread of another process would be a rare event (but seems to be supported.  See [remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx).)'

This is of course just reading between the lines of the documentation.

Comment: The documentation says "The system eventually frees the DLL after [...] all processes that called the hook procedure have resumed processing outside the DLL." which would seem to imply that the DLL is in fact automatically freed, just not immediately?

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, UnhookWindowsHookEx does not unload the .dll. It is unloaded by the message processing code after a new message is received. Therefore some background processes which almost never receive any messages, may still keep the library locked long after your hook was removed. Broadcasting a WM_NULL message usually helps. I like sending it a few times after unhooking.

```
SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_NULL, 0, 0);
```